# Angularjs adding $scope.$watch after $routeProvider's resolve

Tags: angularjs, web, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I'm having an issue where I am trying to watch a certain element from my scope after the resolve is done. For some reason, it gets run when i run the second line from this snippet and I dont seem to be able to add this $watch during the "resolve".

I understand that promises are asynch, but how can I know when my resolve is done to then add the watch?

The variableToWatch can be changed either by code or in the UI (otherwise i would've just used ng-change="doWork()")

```
    $scope.variableToWatch = $route.current.locals.data.initialValue;
    $scope.listOfDependantData = $route.current.locals.data.items;

    $scope.$watch('variableToWatch', function (newValue) {
        myService.getNewDependantData(newValue).$promise.then(
            function (items) {
                $scope.listOfDependantData = items;
            }
        );
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

If you want to run your code only when it *changes* after the initial setting of value, you can use the second form of the `watchFunc` passed as the second argument to `$scope.$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch('variableToWatch', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (typeof newValue !== 'undefined' && newValue !== oldValue) {
        // Use the new value here ...
    }
});
```

---

I don't fully follow the question, but I suspect that you want to watch the value `$route.current.locals.data.initialValue` instead of `$scope.varibleToWatch`?

In that case, you can use the alternate form of `$scope.$watch` with a `function` as the first argument:

```
$scope.$watch(function () { return $route.current.local.data.intialValue; }, function (newValue) {
    // ...
};
```

Or, if you want to watch the variable on your `$scope` which is referenced to by the sting contained in `$route.current.local.data.initialValue`, then you can use this:

```
$scope.$watch(function () { return $scope[$route.current.local.data.intialValue]; }, function (newValue) {
    // ...
};
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: i want to watch $scope.variableToWatch, but my problem is that it runs twice the first time. I don't want it to run initially (when i set the value for the first time).

And it's initial value comes from an asynchronus call.

One thing that could help me is if there was a way to get the promise returned by the "resolve" of the route.

Comment: @LostBalloon Updated the answer. Does that do what you want? Also, I am afraid I do not know of anyway of setting the promise in the controller. You can use side-effects of the promise resolving in your main app to share a value through a service with your controller, but am not sure how that plays with the current structure of your app.